# Why is my function ordering the elements in ascending order instead of a Min Heap?

Tags: c

The numbers I insert are:

> 37 25 43 65 48 84 73 18 79 56 69 32.

But my numbers are being displayed as

> 18 25 32 37 48 43 73 65 79 56 69 84

i.e in ascending order.

It's supposed to be a Min heap with the order of

> 18 37 32 25  48 43 73 65 79 56 69 84

(the order once i did the calculations on paper). Can someone tell me how to fix my function so that its a Min heap and does not give me some weird order?

```
void siftUp(int heap[], int n) {
// Sift the value in heap[n] so that heap[1..n] is a heap
int siftItem = heap[n];
int child = n;
int parent = child / 2;
while (parent > 0) {
    if (siftItem >= heap[parent]) {
        break;
    }
    heap[child] = heap[parent];         // Move the parent down
    child = parent;
    parent = child / 2;
}
heap[child] = siftItem;
}
```

Comment: Your paper calculations are wrong -- you have 25 as a child of 37, which violates the child >= parent invariant for the heap tree.

Comment: I think that operator is wrong, when I change it to <, I get it in max heap order.

Comment: In what you call a "min heap", I assume you expect the top of the heap to be the smallest value... which is what you have.  The values further down are going to be bigger, but not (necessarily) in simple ascending order.  The order you appear to expect is almost the same as what you are getting, except for the 25 and the 37, where clearly the 25 belongs further up the heap.

Comment: `18 25 32 37 48 43 73 65 79 56 69 84` is not "ascending order"

Comment: @mattMcNabb I just noticed that too. But either way, It does not seem to be in the correct order for a Min heap. I could have sworn the correct order is 18 37 32 25 48 43 73 65 79 56 69 84. Unless I calculated it wrong. But it doesn't seem like i did.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem -- C arrays are 0 based rather than 1 based, so your parent computation is off by one.  It should be `parent = (child - 1)/2`.

Comment: For simplicity I initialized the first element to array[1] instead of zero in my program @Chris Dodd

Comment: You should say "for obfuscation" rather than "for simplicity" :-)